# HTML5 semantic threaded comments

Tags: html, semantics

When dealing with threaded comments on a blog in HTML5 would you expect threads of comments to be nested `<article>`'s? Or would you consider even the nested comments to be simply another `<article>` within the scope of the blog post  and the threading is a display issue?

**Example A:**

```
<section>
<article>
...blog post...
<section id="comments">
<article id="comment_1">...comment 1...</article>
<article id="comment_2">
   ...comment 2...
   <article id="comment_3">...comment 3 in response to comment 2...</article>
   <article id="comment_4">
       ...comment 4 in response to comment 2...
       <article id="comment_4">...comment 5 in response to comment 4...</article>
   </article>
</article>
<article id="comment_6">...comment 6...</article>
</section>
</article>
</section>
```

**Example B (with theoretical rel="parent"):**

```
<section>
<article>
...blog post...
<section id="comments">
<article id="comment_1">...comment 1...</article>
<article id="comment_2">...comment 2...</article>
<article id="comment_3" rel="comment_2" class="indent-1">...comment 3 in response to comment 2...</article>
<article id="comment_4" rel="comment_2" class="indent-1">...comment 4 in response to comment 2...</article>
<article id="comment_5" rel="comment_4" class="indent-2">...comment 5 in response to comment 4...</article>
<article id="comment_6">...comment 6...</article>
</section>
</article>
</section>
```

Edit:

To further clarify, it feels like each of the comments being listed as an article in the spec recommendations is because it is an article in a subsection of the main article because of its relevance. And a threaded comment is still an extension of that discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I WANT to agree with Closure Cowboy because to me all of the comments for a given article are in the context of the original article even if there are some tangential threads that could occur. Without the original article the comments would be unimportant. However, a friend gave a good argument for how the secondary comment content can eclipse the importance of the threaded comments:

```
Original Article: "post some awesome photoshops of my dog!"
Comment 1: (link/image of awesome photoshop response that goes crazy viral)
Comment 2: re comment 1: oh wow, that is amazing photoshop skills!
Comment 3: re comment 1: Fantastic! How do you do that?
Comment 4: re comment 3: See this tutorial I found on that effect.
```

At that point we are no longer really discussing the original article at all. While there is a relationship it seems more important to literally represent the semantic relationship by nesting the elements. So I've got to go with "B".

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a news article written by the New York Times. Then, imagine that Newsweek writes an article in response to the article by the New York Times.

The Newsweek article isn't part of the New York Times article; it's simply related to it. If these two articles were displayed on a webpage, the Newsweek article might be *displayed* in a way that indicates that relationship, but it's certainly not part of (or nested in) the New York Times article.